# Large scale Autoencoder for friendship recommendation

Tags: autoencoder

I have a user friendship graph for about 30 Million users. I am trying to use an auto encoder [30 Million, 512, 512, 1024, Dropout(0.3), 512, 512, 30 Million]. But I am not learning anything. 
Has anyone used Autoencoder for Friendship recommendation on a large scale graph?

Answer (score 0):

Autoencoder will not predict potential friendship. Autoencoders learn a lossy compression of the data. A lossy compression of existing friendship relationships will not predict new relationships.

Comment: How do you do link prediction with deep learning? How do you use collaborative filtering for friendship recommendations?

Comment: Those are independent questions. Ask them as independent questions, not comments.